# Wicket DebugBar / DevUtils during production

Tags: debugging, wicket

The Wicket `DebugBar` from `wicket-devutils` adds a lot of useful information when debugging session / serialization issues. The documentation suggest that it should be added to a base page.

This approach seems to provide very weak support for differentiating between development and production environment. I don't want `wicket-devutils` as a production dependency and I most certainly do not want to clutter the code with "if development" branches.

How do "Wicket" people deal with this in real life applications? Are there any established patterns?

http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/devutils/debugbar/DebugBar.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In our case, we only add it when development utilities are enabled.

```
if (getApplication().getDebugSettings().isDevelopmentUtilitiesEnabled()) {
    add(new DebugBar("dev"));
} else {
    add(new EmptyPanel("dev").setVisible(false));
}
```

The dependency is not that big, it is ok for us to let it in our production dependencies.

Comment: It was code like that I was trying to avoid, but I can't really see any decent solutions.

Comment: I don't have a better one, this code will only be added once in your application, it's not big deal. If you really don't want the `if` polluting your page you can still introduce a component doing it.

Comment: It's more the attitude of "it'll only be added once" I don't like. Sooner or later someone makes a mistake and it (or something else) is exposed to the public. For lots of projects this might not be a big deal though.

Comment: `DebugBar` already does this for you in its `isVisible()` method.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/24547617/2048802.

Answer (score 5):

`DebugBar` already overrides `isVisible`. So you do not have to do anything.

```
@Override
public boolean isVisible()
{
    return getApplication().getDebugSettings().isDevelopmentUtilitiesEnabled();
}
```

Comment: Imho this (default) approach is a preferred one. The conditional-add (panel method) is useful for heavyweight components that are expensive to initialize. See: http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Dealing+with+conditional+content